# How to identify and save keywords in the database and retrieve it later in rails 3.1

Tags: full-text-search, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sunspot-rails

I am working on a rails 3.1 app where I have to implement the following logic.

1) Provide a searchbox
2) User enters their query in the searchbox 
3) If the query is not present in the database the user saves the query in the database
4) If a matching query is found it is retrieved and displayed to the user.

I am new to the search business and needs some direction on how to identify what are the keywords which the user has entered in the query?  Is there a gem which can do this?

I am using sunspot for doing the search, how do I customize the sunspot to make the text entered in the searchbox searchable?

Thanks,